# Does Non-maskable interrupts effects processing of critical sections

Tags: operating-system, interrupt, critical-section

My understanding is that a non-maskable interrupt enforces context switching (which causes a process to be moved from CPU to ready queue). If the interrupt happens at a time when the process is executing its critical section, it may make the output indeterministic. One solution is to roll back to the state when the process entered the critical section, but I don't know if that is possible. Please help clarify this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: 'My understanding is that a non-maskable interrupt enforces context switching' you understanding is incorrect.  An NMI happens outside the purview/context of the OS thread scheduler/dispatcher.  It is not safe to directly invoke a scheduler run from an NMI.

Comment: wow, thats interesting. So, it means that NMI enforces the execution of the current thread on CPU to suspend temporary, but the context switching doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

- If there would be a way that roll back would happen, I honestly do not know.
- Yes, there is ways of doing so by software of course, the developer could implement guards in his/her code to check if there is an anomaly if so they are will repeat the process again to avoid the corrupted data.